# android scrollview cropped after soft keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, scrollview

I am having a problem with a scrollView inside a fragment. My tablet application contain two main fragments one for the menu on the left and a other one on the right which contain an editText object and some other stuff.
I am trying to scroll vertically the content of the right fragment when the soft keyboard is showing.

The content scroll in the right fragment is working but after scroll the fragment seem to be cropped on the top and bottom where the system bars appeared while the soft keyboard was showing.

[Layout before and after scroll.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idlNo.png)

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack
                android:id="@+id/card_stack_comment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:clipChildren="false"
                android:clipToPadding="false">
            </com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/general_comment">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_feedback"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text_leave_feedback"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:hint="@string/editText_hint"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:background="@drawable/background_with_border"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

This is how I detect if the keyboard is showing and move the content of the
ScrollView:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    rootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            Rect r = new Rect();
            // r will be populated with the coordinates of your view
            // that area still visible.
            rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
            int heightDiff = rootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

            if (heightDiff > 300) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "keyboard shows up");
                scrollToCurrentFocusedView();
            }else{
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "keyboard vanishes");
                 //try to refresh the scrollView but not working
                 //scrollView.invalidate()
                 //scrollView.requestLayout()
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

protected void scrollToCurrentFocusedView(){
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "calling scrollToCurrentFocusedView");
    View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null && scrollView != null) {
        scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, view.getBottom()-(view.getHeight()*3));
    }
}
```

I tried to refresh the scrollview after the keyboard is hidden with invalidate() and requestLayout() without success.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you detecting keyboard and moving scrollview programmatically?

Comment: use soft input window=adjust pan in your activity tag in manifest file and don't detect keyboard from java code

Comment: input window=adjust pan in the manifest do not allow me to scroll the view when the keyboard is showing which I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by using a customScrollView instead. The important part is to overload the onApplyWindowInsets() function.

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public CustomScrollView(Context pContext, AttributeSet pAttrs, int     pDefStyle) {
        super(pContext, pAttrs, pDefStyle);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context pContext, AttributeSet pAttrs) {
        super(pContext, pAttrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context pContext) {
        super(pContext);
    }

    @Override
    public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {

        if(insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom() < 100){
            WindowInsets newInset = insets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(new Rect(0,0,0,0));
            Log.d("TEST","Keyboard is down");
            return super.onApplyWindowInsets(newInset);
        } else{
            Log.d("TEST","Keyboard is up");
            return super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);
        }
    }

}
```